# What is the default font color in HTML5?

Tags: html, css, default

I know by experience, that if I don't change the font color with CSS, it's always black (#000000). But I was wondering, are there any edge-cases when the default font color is not black?

So I did some google searches [like this](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk035a2td1OUKRxUSFF81BmoDkS_2hg%3A1592306096773&ei=sKnoXtLsLtOM8gLRtYr4BA&q=what%20is%20the%20default%20font%20color%20in%20html5&oq=what%20is%20the%20default%20font%20color%20in%20html5&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1CayARYmsgEYLLJBGgAcAB4AIABggGIAYIBkgEDMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjShJa6mobqAhVThlwKHdGaAk8Q4dUDCAw&uact=5), but I only found readings about how to change the font color.

Did I miss something? Does anyone know where can I further research?

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#foreground --> *Initial: depends on user agent*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default color defined in HTML. The "default color" is configured in the browser or by the operating system you are using.