# Default Color in CSS

Tags: html, css, colors

Pretty new to this. Let's say define the following in my CSS file (no *color* attribute)

```
.time {
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    background: #555555;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all linear 0.3s;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

and then use it like this

```
<div class="time" ...
```

Where does the text color come from? Is there a default, does it use on defined in a previous tag, ...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407333/what-is-the-default-font-color-in-html5

Comment: Is there anywhere to configure that?  The reason I am asking is that we have to environment where the above code is deployed to and in one the text is white and in the other it's black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 cases in this situation:

1. It will take the first color of a parent if a parent has defined a color
2. If the parent has no defined color then it will take the `body` or `html`  color
3. If `html` and `body` elements have not defines color after that it will take browser default color.

Comment: No. If the parent has no defined color, the browser will walk up the HTML element tree until it finds something with a defined color. This is due to `color` being an inherited attribute. `<html>` always has a defined color because that's what the browser targets for setting inheritable CSS attributes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this:

- Some CSS properties are inherited from their parent. `color` is one of those. Technically, `inherit` is `color`'s default value.
- The browser defines various initial values. The initial value for `color` is usually set on the `<html>` element, via a browser-internal CSS stylesheet, and can be different from browser to browser, but is usually black, a color similar to black, or a color designed to contrast with the default background color (in dark mode, for example).

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color

Note that my description isn't 100% technically accurate, but it's pretty close. `color` has been around for a long time and has inherited a bit of baggage over the years.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
body {
 color: "white"
}
```

Change white to any color you want.

Then if you want to override in specific tag, you can set it in class like your `.time` class.